# Cannot access memory locations while sending buffer via UART as USB data to VCP

Tags: debugging, stm32, nucleo

I am implementing a simple found here
https://shawnhymel.com/1795/getting-started-with-stm32-nucleo-usb-virtual-com-port/

In a super while loop, when debugging

```
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */
      uint8_t buffer[] = "hello world";
      **CDC_Transmit_FS(buffer,sizeof(buffer));**
      HAL_Delay(1000);
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
```

*Board:nucleo-L432KC*
*STM32CodeIDE*

[Attach is the image of error while debugging.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOUIn.png)

Comment: Looks like a false positive. Perhaps you are reading these pointers before they've been initialized, so the debugger fails when it tries to follow them.  Try stepping through the code until the structure is properly initialized.

Comment: the structure isnt supposed to be initialized in line 287?

Comment: it is a NULL pointer. USB device has not been initialized successfully

Comment: I think i have now initialized the usb properly, I am getting the error now after debugging
[libusb: error [ udev_hotplug_event ] ignoring udev action bind
}

Comment: The same error arises when the usb is used as a Mass storage device instead of VCP